# Magento - change 3rd part extensions page position

Tags: php, magento

I have installed a custom extension that I have purchased from magento extensions. The module displays above the add to cart button on the product page, inside the column on the right hand side. I would like to move the new extension underneath the image and cart options, out of the right hand side. 
I am a beginner magento developer, I can not figure out how to move this modules position.

Comment: look into this .it may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484955/magento-xml-using-before-after-to-place-blocks-hardly-ever-works

Comment: thanks i will have a read

Comment: ok, the link doesnt explain where the code is, as in which files? I cant find any evidence of the new extension within the local.xml file