# How to add content after or before block using XML in magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to append content in block using XML file. Please check below image

[image]

I have added below code but it is overwriting content. (I want to append).

```
<reference name="order_items">
      <action method="addColumnRender">
         <column>name</column>
         <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
         <template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
      </action> 
</reference>
```

I have checked core file there are creating block programmatically.

Comment: I have read this can you let me know What will be change in my case?
I have tried code of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484955/magento-xml-using-before-after-to-place-blocks-hardly-ever-works link but it is now working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know you can try this way:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
<reference name="order_items">
    <block type="core/template" name="test-1" template="test/template.phtml" after="sales_order_edit"/>
    <block type="core/template" name="test-2" template="test/template.phtml" before="sales_order_edit"/>
</reference>
```

Or in template file you can place your block everywhere you want:

```
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml
```

Comment: I can't make changes in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\tab\info.phtml` file because I am developing extension.
There are any other way to append data in block

Comment: I have checked in code it is creating block using 'addColumnRender'

Comment: ok but in extension can't you override that file to call your block?

Comment: How it is possible?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/62134/how-to-override-core-template-files-from-a-custom-module

Comment: I have check link but I an not able to find name of block

Comment: I have added below code in ".phtml" my file
`<?php 
$_item = $this->getItem();
$block = $this->getLayout()
                ->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_items_column_name')
                ->setTemplate('sales/items/column/name.phtml')
                ->setRenderedBlock($this);

echo $block->setItem($_item)->toHtml();
$option = $_item->getProductOptions();
if(isset($option['customizer_data'])){
    $results = @unserialize($option['customizer_data']);
    $imagePathFull = $results['image']['url'];
    echo "<a target='_blank' href='{$imagePathFull}'>View Customize Image</a>";
}`

Comment: And aslo I have added below code in config.xml file
`<reference name="order_items">
              <action method="addColumnRender">
                 <column>name</column>
                 <block>adminhtml/sales_items_column_name</block>
                 <template>productcustomizer/sales/order/view/additional.phtml</template>
              </action>
        </reference>`

Comment: It is working but I think it is not correct way to add content

Comment: as i know one can manage block via either xml or php function, so if its working go ahead.

Comment: OK, Thank you so much